# python:how to exit if block during interactive mode

Tags: python, interactive-mode

just play with Python, a small question on interactive mode.

steps:

1. enter python interactive mode, following line shows detail on interactive mode List item
2. >>>flag=True
3. >>>if flag:
4. . . .      print("flag is True")
5. after above step, i WANT to exit the whole if block. but if press enter for above line 4, it will start line with "...", which means still in if block.

question: HOW CAN I exit if block and write sth like the following in interactive mode :

```
flag=True
if flag:
    print("flag is True")
print("exit if now ")
```

Comment: Why do you want to use IDLE? And why only in interactive mode

Comment: Press enter again to exit the if block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double Enter will exit the if block in the interactive mode